# Fatal Python error when using SWIG under OSX

Tags: python, macos, swig

I have troubles using a Python interface generated with SWIG (I have OSX 10.11.12). After compiling and linking everything together as such:

```
swig -python erk_integrator.i
gcc -c -fPIC -O3 model.c auxiliary_functions.c timing_functions.c
gcc -c -fPIC -O3 erk_integrator.c erk_integrator_wrap.c -I. -I/usr/local/include/python2.7
gcc -lpython -dynamiclib model.o erk_integrator.o erk_integrator_wrap.o auxiliary_functions.o timing_functions.o -o _erk_integrator.so
```

I try a test script, but Python throws a fatal error:

```
/usr/local/bin/python test_erk.py

Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
Abort trap: 6
```

But when I run

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 test_erk.py
```

everything works as it should. However, I need to use /usr/local/bin/python (from Homebrew) instead of the system Python.

I think something goes wrong in the linking step. Many thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog post helped me solve it: [blog.tim-smith.us/2015/09/python-extension-modules-os-x](http://blog.tim-smith.us/2015/09/python-extension-modules-os-x)

It turns out on OSX you need

```
-undefined dynamic_lookup
```

instead of

```
-lpython
```